# Getting notified of managed package errors

Tags: apex, managed-package

When a client installs your managed package - and then they run into an Exception - how can I be notified of the error and/or the stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the package there is a field to set on who to notify in case of apex errors.

Set that value and you will be notified for **some** of the errors. I recall reading somewhere that you will not receive all errors and it was not specified how SF determines which emails to send. Will try to find that link

[image]

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_handling_managed_errors.htm

> When you create a managed package for Force.com AppExchange, you can
>   specify a user to receive an email notification when an exception
>   occurs that is not caught by Apex. Uncaught exceptions can be thrown
>   from:
>
> - A Visualforce action or getter method
> - A Web service method
> - A trigger